# spring.cloud.vault.fail-fast - does it still work?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-vault-config

We use Spring cloud vault as a credential store in our environment.
The fail fast option does not work when the Vault url returns 404 - no exception is thrown but the application continues to start and goes ahead with Spring default password (since no credentials have been fetched from Vault).

I was checking the logs, searched a little bit and found the following:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-vault/commit/5078a4c133211adb1bb3642cc867b40deed7b0f0

This takes away the VaultClient - does this mean it also takes away the fail-fast option?

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/143